# Apache Camel Salesforce Lazy Login

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a requirement for our salesforce connector written using apache camel. We have a master org that has connected to a client org using OAUTH and stores Refresh Token in it. We want Camel connector to fetch Refresh Token from master-org and then communicate with client org using the refresh token.

I was hoping that I could set up a new salesforce component instance for master-org and then enable Lazy Login on the default/main salesforce component. Once I have got the refresh token from the Master Salesforce instance, I will then set this in Login Configuration and start the component service.

When I do set the lazy configurations, it still starts up the Salesforce consumer endpoints E.g Platform Events subscriptions, and having no token available on startup, it fails.

Any idea, how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy login works well for producers, but since you're using a salesforce consumer, it needs to login immediately.

Look at using a [RouteContoller](https://camel.apache.org/manual/route-controller.html), which will allow the salesforce consumer route to re-attempt startup with delay logic to give your master-org time to provide the refresh token.

Comment: I have tried setting up supervising route controller. But none of the consumer routes appear to be managed by it. So all the salesforce platform event routes get started immediately regardless of this controller. Other Direct/Seda routes do get verified in supervising controller but are ignored as I have configured a pattern for checking routes. RouteId is also setup on salesforce routes.